# Android lifecycle of requestlocationupdates functionality

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to understand how the LocationManager's requestLocationUpdates (using a PendingIntent) works when the calling component moves out of its visible/active lifecyle. I know how to cancel the intent using removeUpdates, and I've read all the documentation of how services, broadcastreceivers, and activities are all started on the main thread of the application, that you can create worker threads so as not to ruin the UI experience, etc., but when it comes to calls like requestLocationUpdates, where the API is taking care of periodically sending the intents, it gets real fuzzy as to what happens to this functionality when the calling Activity goes out of its visible lifetime.  For example, if I call requestLocationUpdates (using the PendingIntent version) from an Activity, and that Activity is stopped by the OS without my code calling removeUpdates for that PendingIntent, do the PendingIntents for the location updates stop being sent?  what if the Activity is paused instead?  If I want the location updates to keep coming even when the activity goes out of its visible lifetime, or even active lifetime, should I call requestLocationUpdates from a service started in a background thread that I create from the Activity?  Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you put the Locmanager in a service(getting of points& storing). You should always assume users like to multitask or at least some users will get a call while using your app. with this implem, you will be relying heavily on intents.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll try that.  BTW do you know of any good documentation on requestLocationUpdates that explains when and why you should call it from different components.  I'm concerned that once I get it working it will work for a while, but because I don't understand it, I may hit a situation where it fails just because it took while to get to that scenario.  I've researched this a bit and it seems most of the answers are along the lines of "try this, it seems to work".  Just concerned that will get me into trouble if I don't understand why I'm implementing it a certain way. Thx

Comment: unfortunately no. I learned it the hard way when i developed a gps workout feature for a fitness app.  don't trust services to stay alive also. android will try to kill it when its really running on low mem.  save your gps points persistently. sqlite maybe.  if you are going to develop a gps tracking app, mytrack is a good reference.    https://code.google.com/p/mytracks/